# Android - RecyclerView item selection issue

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement functionality where if user clicks on one or multiple  items in `RecyclerView` those items are being selected and if user clicks on the same item/items second time those items are being deselected. To show user that the item on which the user has clicked has been selected or deselected an image is shown or hidden.

However, if I click on one of the items in `RecyclerView` multiple items are being selected.

Here is my code so far:

**my_list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvTest"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivItemIsSelected"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/done_256"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.test.www.recyclerviewadaptertest.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rvTest"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView rvTest;
    private RecyclerViewTestAdapter recyclerViewTestAdapter;
    private ArrayList<TestModel> testModels;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        testModels = new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++){
           TestModel testModel = new TestModel("Test nr." + (i+1));
            testModels.add(testModel);
        }

        recyclerViewTestAdapter = new RecyclerViewTestAdapter(testModels);
        rvTest = (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.rvTest);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(MainActivity.this);
        rvTest.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        rvTest.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rvTest.setAdapter(recyclerViewTestAdapter);
    }
}
```

**RecyclerViewTestAdapter .java**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class RecyclerViewTestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<TestModel> testModels;

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView ivItemIsSelected;
        public TextView tvTest;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            ivItemIsSelected = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivItemIsSelected);
            tvTest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);

            view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(ivItemIsSelected.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE){
                        ivItemIsSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else if(ivItemIsSelected.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
                        ivItemIsSelected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    public RecyclerViewTestAdapter(List<TestModel> testModels) {
        this.testModels = testModels;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);

        return new RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        TestModel testModel = testModels.get(position);
        holder.tvTest.setText(testModel.getTestText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return testModels.size();
    }
}
```

**TestModel.java**

```
public class TestModel {

    private String testText;

    public TestModel() {
    }

    public TestModel(String testText) {
        this.testText = testText;
    }

    public String getTestText() {
        return testText;
    }

    public void setTestText(String testText) {
        this.testText = testText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to deselect item in ViewHolder constructor, maybe they are getting recycled and they keep their selection.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais Thanks for your answer. I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not keep the "selected" state in the ViewHolder, as it gets recycled. Keep the "selected" state in the model. Modify your TestModel.java:
public class TestModel {

```
private String testText;
public boolean selected = false;

public TestModel() {
}

public TestModel(String testText) {
    this.testText = testText;
}

public String getTestText() {
    return testText;
}

public void setTestText(String testText) {
    this.testText = testText;
}
```

}

Set a reference to the model item in onBind and set Visibility based on selected flag of item:

```
    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public ImageView ivItemIsSelected;
            public TextView tvTest;
            private TestModel testModel;

            public MyViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                ivItemIsSelected = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivItemIsSelected);
                tvTest = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTest);

                view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        testModel.selected = !testModel.selected;
                       ivItemIsSelected.setVisibility(testModel.selected ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);

                    }
                });
            }
        }

        public RecyclerViewTestAdapter(List<TestModel> testModels) {
            this.testModels = testModels;
        }

        @Override
        public RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.my_list_item, parent, false);

            return new RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder(itemView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerViewTestAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
            testModel = testModels.get(position);
            holder.tvTest.setText(testModel.getTestText());
            holder.ivItemIsSelected.setVisibility(testModel.selected ? View.VISIBLE : View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return testModels.size();
        }
    }
```

There are other ways to achieve this, but the important thing to remember that every time onBindViewHolder is called you have to update everything in it to reflect the item at the specified position. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
  holder.parentLayout.setOnClickListener {

        if (holder.categoryIcon.isSelected) {
            selectedPos = position
        }

        if (selectedPos == position) {
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
            selectedPos = RecyclerView.NO_POSITION
        } else {
            selectedPos = position
            notifyItemChanged(selectedPos)
        }
    }

    if (selectedPos == position) {
        holder.categoryIcon.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.orange))
        holder.categoryIcon.isSelected = true
    } else {
        holder.categoryIcon.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.white))
        holder.categoryIcon.isSelected = false
    }
```